# (Python noob question) How can a function with no parameters still take an argument?

Tags: python, function

My task is to show the first and last character in a tuple. While I am getting my result I can't understand why, since my function has no parameters and my tuple is not a global one(for instance when I put the tup= below x= it shows an error).

```
def find_first_and_last():
    result = (tup[0],tup[-1])
    return result


tup=(1,2,3,4,5)

x=find_first_and_last()

print(x)
```

I've tried researching this on my own, but couldn't find satisfactory answer anywhere. I really want to understand how functions work, so I would welcome any explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Your tuple is a global one.  Python functions need special permission to write to global scope, but not to read from it.

Comment: This might help you learn about variable and function "scope" https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#using-the-legb-rule-for-python-scope

Answer (score -1):

## In short: No. you cannot have a functions that does not take any arguments but still take parameters

In Python, functions can access variables that are defined in their surrounding scope. In your example, even though the function find_first_and_last() does not have any parameters, it can still access the variable tup because tup is defined in the global scope.

When a variable is referenced within a function, Python first looks for that variable within the local scope of the function. If it doesn't find the variable locally, it then searches in the next enclosing scope, which in this case is the global scope. This allows the function to access the variable tup and perform operations on it.

In your code, the function find_first_and_last() accesses the global variable tup and uses it to find the first and last elements of the tuple. The function then returns a tuple containing the first and last elements.

It's important to note that although the function is accessing a variable from the global scope, it is not modifying the global variable itself. It simply reads the value of tup and performs operations on it without changing its contents.

Regarding your comment about an error when placing tup = below x =, it is because the assignment tup = must come before it is used in the function. If you move tup = below x =, the function find_first_and_last() will not be able to find the variable tup because it hasn't been defined yet.